# Android/JVM SQLite database

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm

I'm trying to have a small Android app have its own database, my first take on this was to simply use the Room persistence library, and it worked wonders, it's an awesome library but...

Later on I decided to try something weird and port that app to Desktop too (JVM).

My plan was to have 3 gradle modules:

- common logic
- android (importing common)
- jvm (importing common)

Problem is that... I can't use Room anymore since it would be in the common logic module that's not an android module.

I tried to switch to [Ktorm](https://www.ktorm.org/), and it seemed nice but Ktorm [can't create tables from the schema](https://github.com/kotlin-orm/ktorm/issues/64) so i had to drop it.

Then i tried to switch to [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) since it has the functionality to create tables from the schema, but Exposed has a few problems:

- The JDBC driver for Desktop ([xerial](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc)) is [not supported on android](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/248), so i should use different drivers per platform (for example using [SQLDroid](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid) for android)
- [Its DAO can't have a table with a composite key](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/964) (which i need to have), and not having the DAO would make everything harder in the code since I'd have to issue the queries directly and get a ResultRow, and then convert them to the objects I need.

My last resort would be creating some monstruous class that totally hide the database providing only the minimum read and write methods that i need and has some sort of flag called android and totally change what its methods do if that flag is true or false, so that it would use Room on Android and Exposed on JVM, but it sounds like a **terrible** idea.

Some idea of how would it be possible to create and use a simple SQLite database in both JVM and Android with the same code?

UPDATE:
I'm now using SQLDelight and even though it's not as comfy as Room and its documentation isn't super extensive, it's pretty nice and does what i wanted, figured out writing this could be useful for someone that come across my same doubt.

Comment: `My last resort would be...` i'm not so sure that this would really be such a terrible idea as you make it out to be, it just sounds like a lot of work :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody it's not the work to work that class the first time that scares me, it's more the fact that using two different libraries at the same time will make thing complicated in the long run, if i'll ever need to add a column i'd have to add it in both the DAO from Room and the DSL from Exposed, plus i'd have to change a ton of code since I'd have to add that column to every data access from a ResultRow from Exposed, maintaining the code of that class for future changes would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [SQLlin - A DSL SQLite library for Kotlin Multiplatform.](https://github.com/ctripcorp/SQLlin), which is a Kotlin Multiplatform SQLite library that based on DSL and KSP. You can write SQL statements with your Kotlin code and these can be verified by Kotlin compiler.